# Optimization of quadratic form with band matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

Let $A_1$ be the $N \times N$-matrix for which $a_{i,j} = 1$ for $i=j$ and 0 otherwise. Let $A_2$ be the matrix for which $a_{i,j}=1$ for $|i-j| \leq 1$ and 0 otherwise. Similarly define $A_3$ (which has ones whenever $|i-j| \leq 2$), $A_4$,  etc.

Set 
$$
s_m = (x_1, \dots, x_N) A_m (x_1, \dots, x_N)^T.
$$
Note that 
$$
s_1=\sum_{k=1}^N x_k^2,
$$
that 
$$
s_2 = \sum_{k=1}^N x_k^2 + 2 x_k x_{k+1},
$$ 
that 
$$
s_3 = \sum_{k=1}^N x_k^2 + 2 x_k x_{k+1} + 2 x_k x_{k+2},
$$ 
etc. (actually one has to restrict the summation ranges for the mixed terms a bit, but this is a minor point).

I am interested in the minimal possible value of 
$$
\max \Big( s_1, \frac{s_2}{2},\frac{s_3}{3},\frac{s_4}{4}, \dots, \frac{s_M}{M} \Big),
$$
for some fixed $M$ (assume that $N \to \infty$), under the assumption that $\sum_{k=1}^N x_n = N$ and that all $x_k$'s are non-negative.

A trivial lower bound is N, since $s_1 = \sum x_k^2 \geq \sum x_k = N$. But my impression is that as $M \to \infty$ the value of this maximum should approach 2N.

Furthermore, is it true that as $M \to \infty$ the numbers $x_1, \dots, x_N$ arrange in such a way that they are all roughly of the same size, in order to minimize the maximum? (Note that this is not true for a single fixed $m$; for example, for $m=3$ the $x_k$'s would not arrange as $(1, \dots, 1)$ in order to minimize $s_3$, but rather as $(3,0,0,3,0,0,3,0,0,3,\dots)$.)

Comment: The asked above appeared during my research. I reformulated the key problem and asked again here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255400/minimizing-x-12x-22x-32x-1x-2x-2x-3x-3x-1. There I received some very helpful comments.