# Minimizing $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

Look at the expression 
$$
f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1. 
$$
The numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are non-negative, and I assume that $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$. This is a sum of squares and "cyclic correlations" of consecutive variables. Then you can check that $f$ is minimized for the values $x_1=x_2=x_3=1$.

Now look at
$$
g(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4+x_4x_1,
$$
under the assumption that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4$. Again, this is minimized by $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4=1$.

A similar thing happens if I add "second-order cyclic correlations": Let
$$
h(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4+x_4x_1+x_1x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_1+x_4x_2,
$$
again under the assumption that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4$. This is also minimized for the values $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=1$.

Is there a simple explanation for this? Is there a simple argument showing that the same will happen for, say, 12 variables and correlations of order up to 3?

Comment: If multiplication is commutative, why does $h$ contain both $x_1 x_3$ and $x_3 x_1$? Or, both $x_2 x_4$ and $x_4 x_2$?

Comment: Yes, it is commutative - I wrote it this way to point out the construction of the sum in a more visible way.

Comment: The problem is that you are weighting some monomials more than others. More importantly, are you sure the corresponding symmetric matrix is circulant?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question is about the signature of a quadratic form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \frac12\sum_{1 \le \mathrm{dist}(i,j) \le p} x_ix_j
$$
(or about the spectrum of the corresponding linear operator). The matrix is a circulant matrix, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), and its eigenvectors are
$$
v_k = (1, \omega^k, \ldots, \omega^{k(n-1)}),
$$
where $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$. The eigenvalues are easy to compute:
$$
\lambda_k = \frac12 + \frac12 \sum_{i=-p}^{i = p} \omega^{ki} = \frac12 + \frac12 \frac{\omega^{\frac{(2p+1)k}{2}} - \omega^{\frac{-(2p+1)k}{2}}}{\omega^{\frac{k}2} - \omega^{-\frac{k}2}} = \frac12 + \frac12 \frac{\sin \frac{(2p+1)k\pi}{n}}{\sin \frac{k\pi}{n}}.
$$
Unfortunately, there may be negative eigenvalues. For example, for $n=7$, $p=2$ we have
$$
\lambda_5 = \frac12 + \frac12 \frac{\sin\frac{25\pi}7}{\sin\frac{5\pi}7} < 0.
$$

Thus for seven variables and cyclic sums up to order two the minimum will not be attained at $x_1 = \cdots =x_7 = 1$.

Comment: Why $1/2$ on the diagonal, not 1?

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant - I suppose I would have needed a few years to figure that our myself.

Comment: PS: I don't understand the remark on the negative eigenvalues - I am not familiar with these things. Can I deduce from the eigenvalues a lower bound for the minimal value of the quadratic form? Obviously for all variables equal to one gets $n(p+1)$ - which role do the negative eigenvalues play here, and how far below $n(p+1)$ can it go?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov : because $x_1x_2$ also occurs as $x_2x_1$.

Comment: @Kurisuto Asutora : From the calculus viewpoint we are computing the signature of the matrix of the second derivatives (which happens to be twice the same circular matrix). Minimum corresponds to positive definiteness corresponds to positive eigenvalues. From the linear algebra viewpoint we are finding the principal axes and determining the signature of a quadratic form. Only if all eigenvalues are positive, the level set $Q(x,x) = \mathrm{const}$ will be an ellipsoid, so its tangent hyperplane of the form $\sum_i x_i = \mathrm{const}$ will lie "on the right side" from it.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev this is about non-diagonal entries, but $x_1^2$ corresponds to 1 on the diagonal, does not it?

Comment: @FedorPetrov sorry, I misunderstood. But I am putting 1 on the diagonal. Later, in the first displayed formula this 1 gets split into $\frac12$ and $\frac12 \omega^0$.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev ah, it splits. I see now

Comment: @Ivan: thanks a lot, this is helping greatly. Still, I seem to be missing something. How does the positivity of all eigenvalues imply the desired bound? Is this, roughly speaking, because the eigenvectors are orthogonal? Then the eigenvectors form an orthogonal basis, and we can write every vector as a linear combination. This would mean that the coefficient for the eigenvector (1,...,1) has to be 1, because we assume that $x_1+\dots+x_n=n$, and non-zero coefficients for other basis vectors would give non-negative contribution (since eigenvalues are non-negative) - is this how it works?

Comment: PS: If I understand these things correctly now, I can force all eigenvalues to be positive if I increase the coefficients in the main diagonal a bit (from 1 to 2, say). This might be sufficient for the application I have in mind.

Comment: @KurisutoAsutora The point $(1, \ldots, 1)$ is a critical point of the function restricted to $\sum_i x_i = \mathrm{const}$, because the gradient at this point is proportional to $(1, \ldots, 1)$. Detecting if this critical point is a local (and then the global) minimum is done by the signature of the Hessian. (And $(1, \ldots, 1)$ is a positive direction anyway.) I think this is also more or less what you mean...

Comment: @KurisutoAsutora As for your next comment, if you put $p$ on the diagonal, you will get a positive definite matrix (it is "diagonally dominated", the corresponding quadratic form can be written explicitly as a sum of squares). I'm afraid that if the diagonal entries are smaller than $p$, the form remains negative definite (for some $n$ and $p$).

Comment: @Ivan: okay, thanks. I will have to think about this a bit. In my application, $n$ will be much larger than $p$, so plotting $\lambda_k$ actually looks roughly like a continuous function in $k/n$. To keep this positive one will not need $p$ on the diagonal, but only $p/4$ or so, but this is still by far too much for me.

Comment: On the other hand, negative eigenvalues correspond to eigenvectors whose index $k$ is close to $0$ or $n$. If $p$ remains fixed, then these indices move closer and closer to 0. I will have to think about what this means for my numbers $x_1, \dots, x_n$.

Comment: @KurisutoAsutora Yes, some interesting questions still remain. Your observation about $\frac{p}4$ is interesting.

Comment: If I did not make a mistake, then for $n \gg p$ the minimal eigenvalue has index $k \approx 3n/(2(2p+1))$, and for the eigenvalue you get roughly $1/2-1/2(\sin(3\pi/(2(2p+1))) \approx 1/2 - 3 \pi /(2(2p+1))$. For large $p$ this is roughly $-2/(3 \pi) p \approx - 0.21 p$.

Comment: Also, I just realized that the eigenvectors do not depend on the matrix at all. This gives me more freedom, since I can "average" over different values of $p$. 

(In the last coordinate in your eigenvector there is a typo, this sould probably be $\omega^{(n-1)}$ instead of $\omega^{k(n-1)}$.)

Comment: PS: One more thing I understood. Assume for example $p=9$, and $n=100$. Then for $x_1 = \dots = x_{100} = 1$ the quadratic form has value 1000. However, for the choice $x_1 = x_{11} = x_{21} = x_{31} = \dots =x_{91} = 10$ and all other $x_n$ being zero, the quadratic form also gives 1000. So the situation is not as simple as I thought. These things must also be reflected in the eigenvalues, somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Minimizing $f$ and $h$ subject to the given constraints are **quadratic programs** of the form

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \frac 12 \mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm A \,\mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & 1_n^{\top} \mathrm x = n\\ & \mathrm x \geq\mathrm 0_n\end{array}$$

where

$$\mathrm A := \mathrm I_n + 1_n 1_n^{\top}$$

Let us temporarily ignore the non-negativity constraints. The Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L} (\mathrm x, \lambda) := \frac 12 \, \mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm A \,\mathrm x - \lambda (1_n^{\top} \mathrm x - n)$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish, we obtain

$$\mathrm A \mathrm x = \lambda 1_n \qquad \qquad \qquad 1_n^{\top} \mathrm x = n$$

Hence, we conclude that the minimizers are

$$\bar{\mathrm x} := \left( \frac{n}{1_n^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} 1_n} \right) \mathrm A^{-1} 1_n \qquad \qquad \qquad \bar{\lambda} :=  \frac{n}{1_n^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} 1_n}$$

Using [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), the inverse of $\mathrm A$ is

$$\mathrm A^{-1} = (\mathrm I_n + 1_n 1_n^{\top})^{-1} = \mathrm I_n - \left(\frac{1}{1+n}\right) 1_n 1_n^{\top}$$

Hence,

$$\mathrm A^{-1} 1_n = \frac{1}{1+n} 1_n$$

and

$$1_n^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} 1_n = \frac{n}{1+n}$$

Thus, the minimizer is

$$\bar{\mathrm x} := \left( \frac{n}{1_n^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} 1_n} \right) \mathrm A^{-1} 1_n = \left( \frac{n}{\frac{n}{1+n}} \right) \frac{1}{1+n} 1_n = \color{blue}{1_n}$$

which satisfies the non-negativity constraints.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I think you misunderstood the problem asked. There are not all pairs $x_i x_j$ involed, only those whose indices are not too far apart (modulo $n$). See the way Ivan wrote it in his answer above.

Comment: In the cases of $f$ and $h$, the corresponding matrix is the one above, which is not really a band matrix. One cannot use the above in the case of $g$.

Comment: There might really be a problem unless the maximal distance $p$ (in Ivan's notation from above) is small in comparison with the dimension $n$. However, in my application this is fine: I will have $p$ fixed and $n \to \infty$. Then the matrix surely is a circulant matrix.